# WebSphere Liberty profile and subversion source control

Tags: svn, websphere-liberty

I am new to WebSphere Liberty Profile server. I am wondering how people are doing source control with Liberty Profile and Subversion.

I don't want to source control the entire Liberty Profile server installation, but only the `usr' folder. Here is my scenario.

Liberty server is installed at

```
c:\wlp
```

I used server.env file to change the default location of `usr' folder by setting WLP_USER_DIR variable. The new wlp user folder now lives in a folder that is source controlled under Subversion, i.e.,

```
c:\subversion\depot\myproj\wlp_usr
```

Once I did this, the WebSphere Liberty Server setup tools within RAD 9.0 freaked out. I got lots of NullPointerErrors, when trying to add a new Server to my workspace.

If there is no workaround for the problem of my current scenario, I am willing to change to a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up the tools to understand a server with a different usr directory is possible (being able to keep the Liberty configuration source-controlled is really useful).

Assuming you already have a runtime environment set up for the Liberty server, open your preferences and navigate to **Servers->Runtime Environments**. Edit the server which should be using a source-controlled use directory. On the first panel, click the "Advanced options" link. You'll then have a panel which allows you to specify user directories. Click "New" and navigate to your usr directory. This is easiest if the usr directory is set up as a top-level project in your IDE, but it can be anywhere on the filesystem.